# Fetch Failed using Update Manager

Tags: debian

I'm getting this error message when I try to use Update Manager: 
"Fetch failed: W:Failed to fetch file:/mnt/disk/dists/squeeze/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  File not found"

Any idea what might have happened to the .gz file that it references?  That directory is empty.

Comment: To elicit more responses or help, I think that you're going to have to explain your environment a little more and how you got to this point.  Like what OS/distribution are we talking about here?

Comment: I'm running Debian 6.0.6, amd64.  The system has been stable for over a year with no issues.  The software update tool has worked fine up until this week.  No updates are showing as available, yet I know there are usually several updates per week.  I haven't changed the sources list, so not sure why all of a sudden there are issues with the sources.

Comment: There is no possible way we can answer this question - all of our crystal balls broke in a tragic earthquake. (Think about what you're asking - "Why is this file missing on my computer?" - how are a bunch of strangers on the internet supposed to be able to answer that with the information given?)

Answer (score 2):

You've set up the installation CD, or some other external media, as an installation source in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Just comment or remove it.

Comment: Make sure there's some other accessible mirror in `sources.list` as well.

Comment: something must have gotten corrupted in my system, because it's been working fine for a year with the same sources list.  I removed the file source and added a mirror source for squeeze updates and I no longer get the error message, but I'm also not getting any updates.